# Eclipse word-document reader/text extractor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ms-word

I need to create a script to read data from word documents and process it using Java. When reading it right out of the file, the text get's completely messed up, which is understandable.

My question is if there exists a plugin for Eclipse to extract the text from file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [apache poi](http://poi.apache.org/document/) libraries using `XWPF`

```
XWPFDocument wd = new XWPFDocument(InputStream);
XWPFWordExtractor wde = new XWPFWordExtractor(wd);
```

[general instruction to read a file](https://poi.apache.org/document/quick-guide-xwpf.html)